# Proof of an inequality including logarithms

Tags: inequality, logarithms

$0 <x,y \le 1$

$|y \log y-x\log x|\le|x-y|^{(1-\frac{1}{e})}$

I want to know how to solve this inequality.

Comment: this question look like to prove that $f(x)= x \ln(x)$ is (1-1/e)-Hölder

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: Incidentally, from looking at a graph, it appears that this is true for $0 < x,y \leq 3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$| \log y^y-\log x^x|\le|x-y|^{(1-\frac{1}{e})}$$

Note that both sides of the inequality symmetric around the line $x=y$ on which the equality holds. Thus we can restric the discussion 
to the half plane $x>y$ where 
$$| \log y^y-\log x^x|=\left| \log \frac{x^x}{y^y}\right|$$ 
but for $x>y$
$$\log\frac{x^x}{y^y}
=\log \left(\frac{x}{y^{y/x}}\right)^x=x \log \frac{x}{y^{y/x}}\ge x \log \frac{x}{y}>0$$
Therefore for $x>y$ the question is about
$$ \log x^x-\log y^y\le(x-y)^{(1-\frac{1}{e})}$$

From here I would try to show that there is no point in the range where both partial derivative of 
$$f(x,y)= \log x^x-\log y^y-(x-y)^{(1-\frac{1}{e})}$$
 vanishes and therefore the inequality holds always. But it could be tricky to do it.